# GNU Coreutils `\time --version` and `/bin/true --version` work but `\true --version` does not?

Tags: bash, ubuntu, shell, coreutils

```
$ \time --version
time (GNU Time) UNKNOWN
Copyright (C) 2018 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
...

$ /bin/true --version
true (GNU coreutils) 8.32
Copyright (C) 2020 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
...

$ \true --version

$ echo 'nothing was printed on the previous line'
```

I'm using Ubuntu 22.04, GNU bash, version 5.1.16 (also tested with zsh 5.9).

Comment: Curious, why `\time` instead of `time` (and same for `\true` and `true`)?

Comment: The shell interprets `time` as a keyword instead of looking on `$PATH` for an executable called `time`; `\time` prevents interpretation as a keyword. I assumed `true` was also a keyword, but the answer indicates it is actually a builtin.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In Bash [`time` is a keyword](https://superuser.com/a/1505454/432690) (see `type time`) and `\time` is not interpreted as such. `\time` makes Bash run an external executable which in your case is GNU `time`.

But `true` is a builtin (see `type true`). The fact you can use a backslash to suppress the `time` keyword (or any keyword, e.g. try `\if`) probably misled you into thinking you can use a backslash to suppress a builtin. No, `\true` still runs the builtin, not the GNU `true`. It's quite evident with `\:`; it runs the `:` builtin, not an external `:` executable which *most likely* does not exist in your OS (compare `type -a :` to `type -a true`; or try `env :`).

`help true` describes the builtin, it mentions no options.

> How does `true` decide which behavior?

It seems the builtin ignores all command line arguments, no matter what they are. GNU `true` ignores all command line arguments, unless there is exactly one argument and the argument is `--help` or `--version`.

In Zsh the story is basically the same.

Comment: The [POSIX definition of `true`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/true.html) lists "options: none; operands: none". It is a GNU peculiarity that *everything* respects `--help` and `--version`, even otherwise option-less commands like `true` and `false`.

Comment: And the command modifier should avoid the builtin, yes?

Comment: @IMSoP Many tools (GNU or not) support options not specified by POSIX, e.g. `sort -z`. AFAIK POSIX does not forbid extra options, except where it *explicitly* does. E.g. for `echo` [it states](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2016edition/utilities/echo.html) that "implementations shall not support any options" (and still many implementations support `-n`, `-e`). "Options: none" for `true` means "no options required", not "no options allowed".

Comment: @D.BenKnoble, no, `command true` runs the builtin command. It's still a command. But `command time` avoids the keyword and `command` would also avoid functions.

Comment: Ah, my apologies. Should be `$(type -P true) --version`